# Kotlin Composable how to get String from remember { mutableStateOf("") } for validation

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

In the form there is one field called email, I enter test@test.com, I get MutableState(value=test@test.com)@233816338 , I just want the value as String "test@test.com" . Calling value ( or getValue ) does not work.

```
    data class DiscoveryRequest (
        var email: String = ""
    )
    fun Screen1() {
        
        val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
        
        LoginForm( navController = navController,
                   onClicked = { discoveryRequest -> viewModel.validateForm(discoveryRequest)
                    })
    }


    fun TestForm(navController: NavController, onClicked: (DiscoveryRequest) -> Unit) {
        
        val mEmail = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = mEmail.value,
            onValueChange = { mEmail.value = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Email") },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        
        Button(
            onClick = {
                onClicked(
                    DiscoveryRequest(
                        email = mEmail.toString()
                    )
                )
            }
        )
        
    }

    public fun validateForm(discoveryRequest: DiscoveryRequest) {
        val email:String = discoveryRequest.email
        Log.d("TEST","Email ${email} len:${email.length}")
        if(email.equals("test@test.com",true)) {
            Log.d("TEST", "all good!!!")
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because a [`MutableState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/MutableState) (as returned by [`mutableStateOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateOf(kotlin.Any,androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutationPolicy))) is essentially a wrapper consisting of the `value`:

```
interface MutableState<T> : State<T> {
    override var value: T
}
```

<sup>[(source)](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state?hl=en#state-in-composables)</sup>

To use its value, you'll have to do *`yourState.value`* (not `yourState.toString()`) just like how you did so in your `OutlinedTextField`:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = mEmail.value, // <-- Retrieving the value to be set to the text-field's value
    onValueChange = { mEmail.value = it }, // <-- Updating the value
    label = { Text(text = "Email") },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)
```

Alternatively, you can also import the [`getValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(androidx.compose.runtime.State).getValue(kotlin.Any,kotlin.reflect.KProperty))/[`setValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState).setValue(kotlin.Any,kotlin.reflect.KProperty,kotlin.Any)) [operator functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#property-delegation-operators) from the `androidx.compose.runtime` package to use [Kotlin delegates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html):

```
// Instead of
val myState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

OutlinedTextField(
    value = myState.value, // <-- Retrieving the value to be set to the text-field's value
    onValueChange = { myState.value = it }, // <-- Updating the value
    label = { Text(text = "Email") },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)
```

```
// You can do
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

// Notice how it's "var" instead of "val", and "by" instead of "="
var myState by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

OutlinedTextField(
    value = myState, // <-- Retrieving the value to be set to the text-field's value
    onValueChange = { myState = it }, // <-- Updating the value
    label = { Text(text = "Email") },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)
```

For more info, visit the following links:

- [State and Jetpack Compose > State in composables](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables), which discusses about `MutableState`